Interpretation of MVABUND results
I ran multivariate analysis using the mvabund package on R to see which factors were significant in influencing gut microbiota. When I was running it for just the factor "Line", my results were significant. However, when I ran for Line x Larval Age x Diet, the table shows me that "Line" is no longer a significant factor? Hope someone can help me to understand this better or correct me if I am wrong. Thank you. 


There are a lot of factors that contribute to taking variance away from the main terms in a model that could explain your result.
When adding more factors, and especially interactions with Line, the new terms explain some of the variance that was initially explained by just Line. So it looks not significant.
You can also have collinear individual terms that share the variance that was initially attributed to Line. You can check for collinearity by seeing if any of the individual terms are significantly correlated.
That said, you should look into simplifying your model by iteratively removing non-significant terms, starting with the largest interactions. Eventually, when you get to your minimum adequate model, you may find Line is significant again. But you should also check for things like collinearity.
Maybe this will also help. There is a great discussion here about how variance is explained between type II and type III ANOVAs that really helped me understand model outputs in R, even if it's not the same model.
